# Quick true false integral spherical coordinates question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2\int_{\pi/3}^{2\pi/3}r^2\sin\varphi \operatorname{d}\varphi\operatorname{d}r\operatorname{d}\theta$$
>   represents the volume of the solid enclosed by the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ and the planes $z=1$ and $z=-1$.

This is a true or false question. I see $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ gets transformed into $r^2=4$ i.e. $r=2$ and $z=1$ and $z=-1$ get transformed into $2\cos\varphi=1$ and $2\cos\varphi=-1$, i.e. $\varphi=\pi/3$ and $\varphi=-\pi/3$. The part that is freaking me out, is I've only done problems using spherical coordinates where I do the order of integration as
$$\operatorname{d}r\operatorname{d}\theta\operatorname{d}\varphi.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

false  ... the volume of the cone is missing.

[image]

the volume element in spherical coordinate does not go straight in blocks. It goes radially. If you rotate the below figure by $360^\circ$ and from $\pi/3 \to 2 \pi/3$ with length radius $2$ then the above picture is what you get (including opposite side).
[image]

You should add the volume of the cone (2x) to get the volume you require.